# Can't run node script on JPPF

Tags: java, jppf

I'm trying to install JPPF on my machine but when I'm trying to execute the startNode.sh/bat script, I've got the following message over and over `node process id: 145, uuid: 123BC1D1-D4B5-28AC-CCA9-2FAB7864485B
Attempting connection to the class server at localhost:11111`

I've try it on a Mac and on a Windows machine. Does someone have the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I'm a JPPF developer.
I already answered the same question in [this JPPF forums post](http://www.jppf.org/forums/index.php/topic,8009.0.html), and copying it here in a way that I hope fits SO's Q&A format.

It seems here is a little bit of confusion. "[Local node](http://www.jppf.org/doc/5.2/index.php?title=Configuring_a_JPPF_server#Configuring_a_local_node)" can only apply to a server (also called driver). It means that the server will run a JPPF node inside its own JVM, instead of in a separate JVM.

My understanding of what you are doing is that you try to start a node configured with `jppf.local.node.enabled = true`. Since this configuration property only applies to a server, and no server is started, the messages you see repeating over and over simply indicate that the node is attempting to connect to a server on "localhost", and retrying until it succeeds.